# new text rendered over older text in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I wrote an application in pygame to display some text. The text consist of a counter which is updated every second or so. I am using raspberry pi for this application. So when I use xserver then everything is displayed correctly but if I use sdl_videodriver fbcon for display then static text is displayed correctly but the counter(text) whose value changes is not displayed correctly. The new value of counter is displayed over the older value and thus after few seconds it becomes unreadable. Following is my code

```
class pyscope :

 def __init__(self):
    disp_no = os.getenv("DISPLAY")
    if disp_no:
        print "I'm running under X display = {0}".format(disp_no)
    drivers = ['fbcon', 'directfb', 'svgalib']
    found = False
    for driver in drivers:
        if not os.getenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER'):
            os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', driver)
        try:
            pygame.display.init()
        except pygame.error:
            print 'Driver: {0} failed.'.format(driver)
            continue
        found = True
        break
    if not found:
        raise Exception('No suitable video driver found!')
    size = [1920,1080]
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.font.init()
    pygame.display.update()

def __del__(self):
    "Destructor to make sure pygame shuts down, etc."

def test(self):
    pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
    done=False
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 34, True)
    frame_rate = 20
    count = 0
    while done==False:
        for event in  pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done=True
        high_score = 2270
        plan = 2100
        count = count + 1
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 200, True)
        if count >100:
            count = 12
        output_string = "ACTUAL          %s" %count
        text = font.render(output_string,True,red)
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.screen.blit(text, [250,420])
        output1 = "random          %.2f" %(float(count)/100*100)
        text = font.render(output1,True,red)
        self.screen.blit(text, [250,540])
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(20)
        pygame.display.flip()
scope = pyscope()
scope.test()
time.sleep(10)
```

Thus my question how can I avoid new text being rendered over older text while using sdl_videodriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to `update()` the screen, you should also "clear" it with a color. Before any blitting/drawing, do:

```
self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
```

You currently only do this *once*, when initializing the application. This should be done on each frame, if you want to keep a fresh, new screen on each frame.

Comment: Though I realized this mistake earlier, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like pygame is not clearing the area of the text counter.
Since I don't have access to an raspberry pi I would suggest you to
make sure you clear/update the area where the counter is rendered.

Comment: I think pygame.display.flip() does clearing/update job which I am doing in my code.

Comment: You are using pygame.display.update() without parameters which does the same as display.flip() when receiving no arguments. But it sounds like The Part where you render the counter is not cleared ,maybe you can test this with rendering a black rectangle over the counter and then the new one over it. Like a "partial-clear" . This could give a hint whether it is an error in the flip()/update() or not.

Answer (score 1):

Before blitting out the text, you could clear the screen area with `pygame.draw.rect`

`pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,(0,0,0),text.get_rect())`

Should work OK, as long as your background is a solid color.